# showing the object instead of string

Tags: java, android, tostring

Here i m attaching snap of my problem and code for that.
it shows me only the content as object but shows groupname perfectly.
the snap for this problem is given in as below link just go throught this image

"http://imageupload.org/?d=4DA941521"(snapshot)

=> I want child data of particular groupname but i m getting groupname instead of child data.

code for this

```
package com.bestdambikers;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SectionedDemo extends ListActivity {


    String strUrl = "http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_development/index.php?option=com_ijoomer&plg_name=jomsocial&pview=user&ptask=field_list&userid=80&sessionid="+ConstantData.session_id+"&tmpl=component";
      DetailBean dBean;
      XmlParser parser;
      ArrayList<Object>  result;
      List<DetailBean> list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.header_main);

        //dBean = new DetailBean();
        parser = new XmlParser(strUrl, new DetailBean());
        result = parser.ParseUrl("data", "group");
        int r = result.size();

        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
        {

            dBean = (DetailBean)result.get(i);
            list=Arrays.asList(dBean);
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            adapter.addSection(dBean.group_name,
                new ArrayAdapter<DetailBean>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        list));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    SectionedAdapter adapter=new SectionedAdapter() {
        protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
                View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView result=(TextView)convertView;

            if (convertView==null) {
                result=(TextView)getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.header,
                        null);
            }

            result.setText(caption);

            return(result);
        }
    };
}
```

DetailBean.java

```
public class DetailBean
{
    public String data = null;
    public String code = null;
    public String fields = null;
    public String group_name = null;
    public String field = null;
    public String id = null;
    public String name = null;
    public String value = null;
    public String status = null;
    public String required = null;
    public String type = null;

    public DetailBean()
    {
        this("","","","","","","","","","","");
    }

    public DetailBean(String data,String code,String fields, String group_name,String field, String id,String name,String value,String status,String required,String type)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.code = code;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.group_name = group_name;
        this.field = field;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.status = status;
        this.required = required;
        this.type = type;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are getting a `String` in your `getHeaderView` method's `caption` parameter that is made by detailBeanInstance.toString().

You should override the `toString` method in DetailBean class to return what you want.

Such an override would be:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    //You should populate this string with the data 
    //you need inside the TextView
    return this.group_name + " " + this.data;
}
```

Place the method above inside your DetailBean class, so it would look like:

```
public class DetailBean
{
    // You should use private members, and create getters and setters to them
    public String data = null;
    public String code = null;
    public String fields = null;
    public String group_name = null;
    public String field = null;
    public String id = null;
    public String name = null;
    public String value = null;
    public String status = null;
    public String required = null;
    public String type = null;

    public DetailBean()
    {
        this("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
    }

    public DetailBean(String data, String code, String fields, 
            String group_name, String field, String id, String name,
            String value, String status, String required, String type)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.code = code;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.group_name = group_name;
        this.field = field;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.status = status;
        this.required = required;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // You should populate this string with the data
        // you need inside the TextView
        return this.group_name + " " + this.data;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also adding here Detailbean class. So plz give me idea what to do in it.

Comment: i've extended my answer with a sample `toString()` implementation.

Comment: thanks..it works for converting from object to string(getting group name instead of child data) but i want the child data of group name.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a hierarchical list in a flat representation? So the group_name actually equals to an other DetailBean instance's name property, and you'd like to display this second name?

Comment: Probably you should ask this in a new question (because it is not a logical extension of the current one), and link this question to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DetailBean` is missing a `toString()` method so that the method from the parent (i.e. `Object`) is taken, which just prints the classname + its address.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to update DetailBean to include overriding the toString method to retrieve whatever String representation you want for the DetailBean objects.

(Ah.  I was beaten by 4 minutes and 2 minutes.)