# want to print group name and its child data

Tags: android, parsing, listview

here

i am trying to print dynamically particular group name and its child data like header and its contents .

but i m able to pring group name in header that is no issue.

But the problem is, i m also getting the group name instead of child contents

[link to my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685084/showing-the-object-instead-of-string/5685113#5685113)

here is the code:
SectionDemo.java

```
package com.bestdambikers;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class SectionedDemo extends ListActivity {


    String strUrl = "http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_development/index.php?option=com_ijoomer&plg_name=jomsocial&pview=user&ptask=field_list&userid=80&sessionid="+ConstantData.session_id+"&tmpl=component";
      DetailBean dBean;
      XmlParser parser;
      ArrayList<Object>  result;
      List<DetailBean> list;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.header_main);

        //dBean = new DetailBean();
        parser = new XmlParser(strUrl, new DetailBean());
        result = parser.ParseUrl("data", "group");
        int r = result.size();

        for(int i=0; i<result.size(); i++)
        {

            dBean = (DetailBean)result.get(i);
            list=Arrays.asList(dBean);
            Collections.shuffle(list);
            adapter.addSection(dBean.group_name,
                new ArrayAdapter<DetailBean>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        list));
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    SectionedAdapter adapter=new SectionedAdapter() {
        protected View getHeaderView(String caption, int index,
                View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView result=(TextView)convertView;

            if (convertView==null) {
                result=(TextView)getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.header,
                        null);
            }

            result.setText(caption);

            return(result);
        }
    };
}
```

and code for `DetailBean.java`

```
public class DetailBean
{
    public String data = null;
    public String code = null;
    public String fields = null;
    public String group_name = null;
    public String field = null;
    public String id = null;
    public String name = null;
    public String value = null;
    public String status = null;
    public String required = null;
    public String type = null;

    public DetailBean()
    {
        this("","","","","","","","","","","");
    }

    public DetailBean(String data,String code,String fields, String group_name,String field, String id,String name,String value,String status,String required,String type)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.code = code;
        this.fields = fields;
        this.group_name = group_name;
        this.field = field;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.status = status;
        this.required = required;
        this.type = type;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // You should populate this string with the data
        // you need inside the TextView
        return this.group_name + " " + this.data;
    }
}
```

xml file which i want to parse

```
<data>
    <code>1</code>
    <fields>
        <group>
            <group_name>Basic Information</group_name>
            <field>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>Gender</name>
                <value>female</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>select</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>3</id>
                <name>Birthday</name>
                <value>05-06-2011</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>date</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>4</id>
                <name>About me</name>
                <value>Well meet me u will come to know</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>textarea</type>
            </field>
        </group>
        <group>
            <group_name>Contact Information</group_name>
            <field>
                <id>6</id>
                <name>Mobile phone</name>
                <value>5555555555</value>
                <required>0</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>7</id>
                <name>Land phone</name>
                <value>6666666666</value>
                <required>0</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>8</id>
                <name>Address</name>
                <value>Tassel global</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>textarea</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>9</id>
                <name>State</name>
                <value>Gujarat</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>10</id>
                <name>City / Town</name>
                <value>Ahmedabad</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>11</id>
                <name>Country</name>
                <value>India</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>country</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>12</id>
                <name>Website</name>
                <value>http://www.google.com</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>url</type>
            </field>
        </group>
        <group>
            <group_name>Education</group_name>
            <field>
                <id>14</id>
                <name>College / University</name>
                <value>California university</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
            <field>
                <id>15</id>
                <name>Graduation Year</name>
                <value>2010</value>
                <required>1</required>
                <type>text</type>
            </field>
        </group>
    </fields>
</data>
```

**XmlParser.java**

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
import android.util.Log;
public class XmlParser extends DefaultHandler
{
    public String RootElement;
    public String RecordElement;
    public InputStream in;
    public Object mainObj;
    public Object newObj;
    public boolean inProcess;
    public String xmlURL;
    public ArrayList<Object> Records = null;
    private final String TAG = "XmlParser";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    String elementName;
    String elementValue;

    public XmlParser(final InputStream is, final Object tempObj)
    {
        this.in = is;
        this.mainObj = tempObj;
        Log.i("Object value", "" + this.mainObj);
        this.inProcess = false;
    }

    public XmlParser(final String strURL, final Object tempObj)
    {
        this.xmlURL = strURL;
        this.mainObj = tempObj;
        this.inProcess = false;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> ParseUrl(final String rootElement, final String recordElement)
    {
        this.RootElement = rootElement;
        Log.i("RootElement", this.RootElement);
        this.RecordElement = recordElement;
        Log.i("RecordElement", this.RecordElement);
        try
        {
            final URL sourceUrl = new URL(this.xmlURL);
            Log.d("URl", this.xmlURL);
            final SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            final SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            final XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(this);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return this.Records;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> parse(final String rootElement, final String recordElement)
    {
        this.RootElement = rootElement;
        this.RecordElement = recordElement;
        Log.i("Root Element", "" + this.RootElement);
        Log.i("Record Element", "" + this.RecordElement);
        try
        {
            final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(this.in, this);
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return this.Records;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String Uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName, final Attributes attributes)throws SAXException
    {
        Log.d("URl", this.xmlURL);
        this.elementValue = "";
        Log.i("IN STARTELEMENT", "" + this.elementValue);
        if (localName.length() > 0)
        {
            Log.i("Local Name Length", "" + localName.length());
            Log.i("LocalName", "" + localName);
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.RootElement))
            {
                this.Records = new ArrayList<Object>();
                Log.i("Root element", "" + this.RootElement);
                Log.i("Records", "" + this.Records);
            }
            else
                if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.RecordElement))
                {
                    this.newObj = ClassUtils.newObject(this.mainObj);
                    Log.i("Main Object", "" + this.mainObj);
                    Log.i("Record element", "" + this.RecordElement);
                    ClassUtils.objectMapping(this.newObj, localName, this.elementValue);
                    Log.i("Element Value", "" + this.elementValue);
                    this.inProcess = true;
                }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, 
            final int length) throws SAXException
    {
        this.elementValue += new String(ch, start, length).trim();
        Log.i("CHARACTERS VALUE", "" + this.elementValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String Uri, final String localName, 
            final String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(this.RecordElement))
        {
            this.Records.add(this.newObj);
            this.inProcess = false;
        }
        else
            if (this.inProcess)
                ClassUtils.objectMapping(this.newObj, localName, this.elementValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `group_name` member is String, it does not have a member called `child_data`. Maybe you should restructurate your `DetailBean` class, and fill it with the correct data.

Comment: Please post your code here rather than link to it elsewhere where it could be edited or deleted.

Comment: i am getting the statically.There are child contents like address,b'date in Basic Information group.

Comment: @Saurabh I don't think it is very clear. How is your group_name related to the child content?

Comment: in each field tag there is group name and child data tag

Comment: here i assume "child data tag" would be the `<field />` tags. but since there are a few of them in each `group`, you should specify how exactly you'd like to "print" them out??? did you consider using an ExpandableListView for this clearly hierarchical data, or you're stick to the ListView? I'd like to see your XmlParser source, to figure out how to build your hierarchical data instead of this flat one.

Comment: please see as you told me i also attached parser class. Please go through this and reply me soon.

Comment: I've posted a sample that displays your xml data in a hierarchical view (the checkboxes stand for the `required` tag). Let me know, if this kind of display is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Your xml suggests that you are dealing with a hierarchical data structure, so my advice would be to use `ExpandableListView` with a proper `adapter`.

Your bean structure should be rethought as well, to be able to hold hierarchy. For this you should split your `DetailBean` class, and leave in that only the `groupName`, `code` and `fields` members:

**DetailBean.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetailBean
{
    private String groupName = null;
    private int code;
    private ArrayList<Field> fields;

    public String getGroupName()
    {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName)
    {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }

    public int getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public ArrayList<Field> getFields()
    {
        return fields;
    }

    public void setFields(ArrayList<Field> fields)
    {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // You should populate this string with the data
        // you need inside the TextView
        return this.groupName;
    }
}
```

And declare a new class named Field, to gather the child data:

**Field.java**

```
public class Field
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private boolean required;
    private String type;

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public boolean isRequired()
    {
        return required;
    }
    public void setRequired(boolean required)
    {
        this.required = required;
    }
    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

I'd split the XmlParser class too, to have the handler part in a different class:

**XmlHandler.java**

```
public class XmlHandler extends DefaultHandler
{
    private static final String TAG_GROUP = "group";
    private static final String TAG_GROUPNAME = "group_name";
    private static final String TAG_FIELD = "field";
    private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_VALUE = "value";
    private static final String TAG_REQUIRED = "required";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private int code = 0;
    private String currentNodeName;
    private DetailBean currentGroup;
    private Field currentField;

    private ArrayList<DetailBean> records = null;
    private String elementValue;

    public ArrayList<DetailBean> getRecords()
    {
        return records;
    }

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException
    {
        super.startDocument();
        this.records = new ArrayList<DetailBean>();
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(final String Uri, final String localName, final String qName, 
            final Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName != null)
        {
            currentNodeName = localName;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(final char[] ch, final int start, final int length) throws SAXException
    {
        if (this.currentNodeName == null)
            return;
        this.elementValue = new String(ch, start, length).trim();

        if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_CODE))
        {
            this.code = Integer.parseInt(this.elementValue);
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_GROUP))
        {
            this.currentGroup = new DetailBean();
            this.currentGroup.setCode(this.code);
            this.currentGroup.setFields(new ArrayList<Field>());
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_GROUPNAME))
        {
            this.currentGroup.setGroupName(this.elementValue);
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_FIELD))
        {
            this.currentField = new Field();
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_ID))
        {
            this.currentField.setId(Integer.parseInt(this.elementValue));
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_NAME))
        {
            this.currentField.setName(this.elementValue);
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_VALUE))
        {
            this.currentField.setValue(this.elementValue);
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_REQUIRED))
        {
            this.currentField.setRequired(Integer.parseInt(this.elementValue) > 0);
        }
        else if (this.currentNodeName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_TYPE))
        {
            this.currentField.setType(this.elementValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(final String Uri, final String localName, final String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_GROUP))
        {
            if (this.currentGroup != null)
                this.records.add(this.currentGroup);
        }
        else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAG_FIELD))
        {
            if ((this.currentGroup != null) && (this.currentField != null))
                this.currentGroup.getFields().add(this.currentField);
        }
        currentNodeName = null;
    }
}
```

So your `XmlParser` class gets simpler:

**XmlParser.java**

```
public class XmlParser
{
    public ArrayList<DetailBean> parseFromUrl(final String xmlURL)
    {
        try
        {
            final URL sourceUrl = new URL(xmlURL);
            Log.d("URL", xmlURL);
            final SAXParser sp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            final XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
            final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
            reader.setContentHandler(handler);
            reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
            return handler.getRecords();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", "Error parsing from url", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<DetailBean> parseFromInputStream(final InputStream in)
    {
        try
        {
            final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
            parser.parse(in, handler);
            return handler.getRecords();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", "Error parsing from InputStream", e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<DetailBean> parseFromInputSource(final InputSource is)
    {
        try
        {
            final SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
            final XmlHandler handler = new XmlHandler();
            parser.parse(is, handler);
            return handler.getRecords();
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("Error", "Error parsing from InputSource", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Your `SectionedDemo` activity should extend `ExpandableListActivity` instead of `ListActivity`, and its `onCreate` method should look like:

@Override

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
    getExpandableListView().setDivider(null);
    getExpandableListView().setDividerHeight(0);

    parser = new XmlParser();
    result = parser.parseFromUrl(XML_URL);
    adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Here is a sample output of an application following the instructions above, and using the xml source you provided:

[image: sample application output]

Here is my main activity class for producing this output (without any resource code):

```
public class SectionedDemo extends ExpandableListActivity
{
    private static final String XML_URL = "http://192.168.5.10/ijoomer_development/index.php?" +
        "option=com_ijoomer&plg_name=jomsocial&pview=user&ptask=field_list&userid=80&" +
        "sessionid=" + /*ConstantData.session_id +*/ "&tmpl=component";

    private MyExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    private XmlParser parser;
    private ArrayList<DetailBean> result;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
        getExpandableListView().setDivider(null);
        getExpandableListView().setDividerHeight(0);

        parser = new XmlParser();
        result = parser.parseFromUrl(XML_URL);
        adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
    {
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyExpandableListAdapter()
        {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(SectionedDemo.this);
        }

        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
        {
            final DetailBean group = result.get(groupPosition);
            convertView =
                    isExpanded ? inflater.inflate(R.layout.grouprow_expanded, parentView, false) : inflater.inflate(
                            R.layout.grouprow, parentView, false);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(isExpanded ? R.drawable.back_grouprow_ok_exp : R.drawable.back_grouprow_ok);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupname)).setText(group.getGroupName());
            if (isExpanded)
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code)).setText("code " + group.getCode());
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView)
        {
            final DetailBean group = result.get(groupPosition);
            final Field field = group.getFields().get(childPosition);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childrow, parentView, false);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(field.isRequired() ? R.drawable.back_childrow_critical
                    : R.drawable.back_childrow_unknown);
            convertView.findViewById(R.id.fieldname).setBackgroundResource(
                    field.isRequired() ? R.color.red_fader : R.color.blue_fader);
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fieldname)).setText("Name: " + field.getName());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.value)).setText("Value: " + field.getValue());
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id)).setText("ID: " + field.getId() + "");
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type)).setText("Type: " + field.getType());

            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.required);
            checkbox.setChecked(field.isRequired());
            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return result.get(groupPosition).getFields().get(childPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return childPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
        {
            return result.get(groupPosition).getFields().size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
        {
            return result.get(groupPosition);
        }

        @Override
        public int getGroupCount()
        {
            return result.size();
        }

        @Override
        public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
        {
            return groupPosition;
        }

        @Override
        public void notifyDataSetChanged()
        {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty()
        {
            return ((result == null) || result.isEmpty());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```